# automatic processing of function in different datasets in R

Tags: r, function, subset

The following function is working with the dataset data21

```
charaFun <- function(col, data=data21) {
    locus<-data[,col]
    mean(locus, na.rm=T)
    }
charaFun("TAPSE")
```

Now i want it to be applied to another datasets e.g. "data211","data212","data21m1","data21w2" which are subsets of data21 which specific conditions.
How can i achieve this automatically?

Answer (score 0):

You could place the datasets in a `list` and use `lapply` to process it all at once.

```
 lst1 <- list(data211, data212, dat21m1, data21w2)
```

Or if the object names have a specific pattern

```
 lst1 <- mget(ls(pattern="data\\d+"))


 lapply(lst1, function(x) charaFun("TAPSE", data=x))
```